# diagnosing errors with mod_auth_mysql

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, mod-auth-mysql

So I installed `mod_auth_mysql` via the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql 
sudo a2enmod auth_mysql 
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I updated my `.htaccess` file to make it connect to the DB as well but it's not working. Here's what I'm getting in the error logs:

> [Wed Aug 07 16:35:23 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] user
>   username not found: /admin/, referer: https://www.domain.tld/

The username very definitely does exist. If I do `SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE userName = 'username'` it comes up. So I'm at a bit of a loss.

Is there a way I could see the SQL `mod_auth_mysql` is generating?

From my `.htaccess` file...

```
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthUserFile /dev/null
Auth_MYSQL On
Auth_MySQL_Host localhost
Auth_MySQL_User username
Auth_MySQL_Password password
Auth_MySQL_Authoritative On
Auth_MySQL_DB "dbname"
Auth_MySQL_Password_Table "apache_auth"
Auth_MySQL_Username_Field username
Auth_MySQL_Password_Field password
Auth_MySQL_Group_Field group
Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types Plaintext
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To see what queries are produced by auth_mysql, it is best to  [log queries via mysql query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) and inspect there what exactly is going on.

I had similar problems, finnaly got auth_mysql working up using this configuration:

```
AuthType                        Basic
AuthName                        "Access Authorization"
AuthUserFile                    /dev/null
AuthGroupFile                   /dev/null
AuthBasicAuthoritative          Off
AuthMYSQL                       On
AuthMySQL_Authoritative         On
AuthMySQL_Non_Persistent        On
AuthMySQL_Socket                /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
AuthMySQL_DB                    my_database_name
AuthMySQL_User                  my_database_user_name
AuthMySQL_Password              my_database_user_pass
AuthMySQL_Group_Table           groups
AuthMySQL_Group_User_Field      user
AuthMySQL_Group_Field           project_group
AuthMySQL_Password_Table        users
AuthMySQL_Username_Field        name
AuthMySQL_Password_Field        pass
AuthMySQL_Empty_Passwords       off
AuthMySQL_Encryption_Types      Crypt_DES

require group admin #requirement on group, valid_user,...
```

and mysql tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
 `user` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
 `project_group` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 KEY `group` (`project_group`),
 KEY `user` (`user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `name` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
 `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Crypt_DES',
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `country_limits` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
 KEY `pass` (`pass`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Hope this will help.